# Setting up WSO2 stratos on local computer

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

I downloaded the latest version of WSO2Stratos from the website and unzipped it on my local computer. I copy the text in the read me file to the /etc/hosts file.

When I run particular services e.g., manager, as, and ESB it works fine without an error.

When I use a browser to login to the page `"https://localhost:9443/carbon/"`

It works fine and possible to see the main page.

After this when I click on any option available, nothing working and I see a only blank page. When I click app manager, ESB or anything on the left side panel, I don't see another page. I see only the main page.

why I cannot see the services offered by stratos live.

Comment: Try the pre-configured Stratos 1.6.0 setup from http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos. Everything is pre-configured.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Stratos 1.6 version is more easier to install and configure. Refer to [Insallation guide blog post](http://meetudara.blogspot.com/2013/02/wso2-stratos-16-how-to-intall-and.html)  here

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not enabled Single Sign On option in your Stratos setup.You need to add following entry to ~/.bashrc  to enable SSO.

export SSO_ENABLED=true

The option Single Sign-On means that once a user logs in to a single service, eg: Stratos Manager using their credentials they will automatically be signed in to any other service eg: ESB or Governance.

Additionally [this](http://msmshariq.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-wso2-stratos-on-local.html) blogpost will help you.